# Linux 3.x init ramdisk embedded in bzImage?

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, ramdisk

Is the initial ramdisk embedded into the `bzImage`?
How to load an `rootfs.cpio` as a ramdisk and switch the `root`?

Comment: No, it is not. See [ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt). The initramfs image file name is specified to the kernel using `initrd` parameter. For details see [kernel-parameters.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt).

Comment: `initramfs` actually can be embedded into the kernel as a cpio archive, while `initrd` can't. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444917/initrd-ramdisk-initramfs-uclinux (which actually should be migrated here).

Answer (score 2):

The bootloader (lilo or GRUB for example) loads the cpio initramfs (unless embedded as a blob in the kernel) or initramd and passes that to the kernel when booting it.

It is normally specified with the `initrd` directive in the bootloader configuration file.

If you use initrd you will typically specify the root filesystem device as `root=/dev/ram0` on the kernel command line (specified with the `append` directive to lilo, for example).

After unpacking/mounting the initramfs/initrd, the kernel will execute `/linuxrc` if it exists, which will typically be a script that mounts the real root filesystem and switches to it with `pivot_root` (older) or `switch_root` (newer).

The `init` command line parameter can be set to another executable/script to execute instead of `linuxrc`. Try passing `init=/bin/sh` to the kernel on your next boot.

Answer (score 0):

The initial ramdisk is not traditionally embedded in `bzImage`, though it can be. Instead it is stored in a second file and specified using the `init` directive.

The method your `rootfs.cpio` file uses to switch the root is up to whatever generated that file, but traditionally, `pivot_root /new_root` or `switch_root /new_root` is used to switch to the new root.